# dreamhost | connecting mysql remotely over https

Tags: mysql, https, remote-access, dreamhost

I am trying to Connect to a MySQL Database from Third-Party Programs as mentioned here:
http://wiki.dreamhost.com/MySQL  (see section: Connect to MySQL Database from Third-Party Programs)

I have uploaded 'sqlbuddy' on another domain (hosted somewhere else) and in dreamhost panel Under the section titled 'Allowable Hosts' I have put that domain name.

When I try to connect to sqlbuddy without https it connects fine (like http://domain.com/sqlbuddy),
but when I try to access sqlbuddy over https (like https://doman.com/sqlbuddy) it shows can't connect error.

Comment: why downvote, kindly explain

Comment: I don't know why whoever voted did so, but I can say your question is confusing.  What isn't connecting over https, to where?  What error do you get when you try?  Is this "another domain" hosted on dreamhost or somewhere else?  Fix your question and maybe whoever downvoted it will undo it.

Comment: i have answered these questions..

Answer (score 1):

SQLBuddy is a PHP web application.  From your question I can see that you are using DreamHost for web hosting and I am going to assume that you are using them to host SQLBuddy.  From the DreamHost [compare our products web page](http://dreamhost.com/servers/compare-our-products/),  the use of SSL requires a dedicated IP address which is optional.  Have you have a dedicated IP address with their service?  Are you using your own SSL certificate or did you purchase on e from them?

Comment: My understanding of the question is that `domain.com` is somewhere other than dreamhost, but all of this applies to wherever `domain.com` is.

Comment: @DerfK Yes, I see what you mean, he did say that SQLBuddy is hosted outside of DreamHost.